# What causes CSS, HTML, javascript, or React to combine margins?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I have an element with a margin at the bottom of `10px`. And immediately under this element, I place another element with margin at the top of `10px`.

Now there is exactly `20px` of whitespace between these 2 elements.

What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Not sure I follow as that is expected. What is your expectation?

Comment: Margins by default overlap? So there should only be `10px` of margin between these 2 elements

Comment: Why would there not be 20px? We need to see the markup and css to say why it would be 20 or 10

Comment: Not in all cases, if you have `display: flex;` on the parent it will. Just curious what's the reason to add bottom and top in this case? :)

Comment: @Dejan.S That fixed it. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you're giving some default margin in the body section.

So you can try saving this using:

body{
margin:0
}